# Get all String resources used in activity

Tags: android, resources

Is it possible to create a method that would return an array/list of all R.String resources used in an activity?

I'd need something like:

1. I enter ActivityA
2. I put to onResume

   ```
   Log.d(TAG, "Strings used in ActivityA: " + getStringsFromCurrentActivity());
   ```
3. I enter ActivityB and use this method again.
4. (...)

Answer (score 0):

what is the purpose?

you should define yours Strings in the String.xml file.
Than you should use

```
String str = getResources().getString(R.string.str_1);
```

---

If you want to, you can write a method like:
(but i absolutely see no need to do this)

```
String [] getStringsForActivity(){
    ArrayList<String> al = new ArrayList();
    al.put( getResources().getString(R.string.str_1));
    al.put( getResources().getString(R.string.xxx));

    String[] ar = new String[al.size()];
    return al.toArray(ar);
}
```

Comment: Need is a bit weird because I need to create log for translation team. I wanted to create automation tests that go through each window in the app and takes into log all string/key from activities it goes through. That way I could provide all strings from each window with screenshot of that window and make it automatic.

Comment: maybe you can write a method in the which log every Sting you reed from String.xml. Create a Method which search the String, log the String and than return the String. Use this Method every time yu read a String from the xml file.

Comment: well yeah it's an idea, but not every string is provided by getString() method and some of them are just hardcoded in xml layout of activity. I don't know if the thing I want to achieve is even possible but I asked this question because someone maybe will surprise me with some good solution/hint/workaround.

Comment: My another idea is to get access to current view hierarchy and save in array every string located in "text" and "placeholder" field of each view in hierarchy.